# Change url images on a user control

Tags: asp.net, image, ascx, compiled

I have same compiled user controls (.ascx) and I don't have the code behind. This user controls have some images and the source is defined in code behind. Do you have any idea how I can change the source path images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dirty way would be to overwrite the path using jQuery.

The clean way would be a new Control which implements the original one.
Now you should be able to overwrite the original functionality.

Here's a little example:

```
    public partial class NewControl : OriginalControl
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
           base.OnInit(e);
           imageControl.Attribute = "new/path/to/img.jpg";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override an event in the markup, like this:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/some_image.jpg";
    }  
</script>
```